# Dart - Date Differences

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I know there's a pre-function `differences` for DateTime to calculate the duration differences between two DateTime. But I need to calculate the **date** differences between two `DateTime`. For example, the differences between `2020-03-01 23:59:59` and `2020-03-02 00:00:01` should return 1. How can I do that? Thanks in advances

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61268546/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create another two DateTime objects using only the year , month and day of the months of the previous dates using the 'DateTime' constructor  it should work.
Like so :

```
DateTime date1,date2;//These should be initialized 
Duration difference = DateTime(date1.year,date1.month,date1.day).diffrence (DateTime(date2.year,date2.month,date2.day)); 
print (diffrence.inDays);
```