# Is there a better way to compare a date against another?

Tags: flutter, dart

My code is:

```
  for (var rt in list) {
    if (rt.date.day == date2.day &&
        rt.date.month == date2.month &&
        rt.date.year == date2.year) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Is there a better way to compare a date against another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a helper function to strip off the time:

```dart
DateTime dateOnly(DateTime dateTime) => DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, dateTime.day);
```

and then you can use `DateTime`'s normal [`operator ==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/operator_equals.html):

```dart
if (dateOnly(rt.date) == dateOnly(date2)) {
  ...
}
```

Note that the above example assumes both dates are in the same time zone.  If they might be in different time zones, you should precisely define what it means for two `DateTime`s to have the same "date" and convert both to a common time zone (possibly UTC).

Comment: It didn't work. I think it is because the dates values were taken in different ways, the code I'm using is more complex that above. But by printing them I got this:

date1: 2020-05-01 21:05:02.543195
date2: 2020-05-01 21:33:13.633851

They are the same date but not the same time.

Comment: @JoanFarfánArmas Oh, I did not realize that you did not care about the time.  In that case, you could write [a helper function to discard the times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61268546/179715) and then compare the results.

Comment: thanks @jamesdlin, it worked perfectly and it is good to have a function for this across my app.

Answer (score 1):

Use `difference`:

```
 for (var rt in list) {
    if (rt.date.difference(date2).inDays == 0) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Documentation link:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html

Comment: For some reason, by using it, when I compare "date" with each date of the week (since all the code above is inside a loop of the last 7 days, date2 gets each of them), it matches with today and yesterday... However by using the code I wrote, it only matches with today. I think this way is not accurate...

Comment: That's weird. I have tested the code in dartpad before answering and it worked perfectly. what are you exactly trying to compare?
[Try this answer it might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60782895/9216793)

Comment: Note that this will treat 23:30 on 2019-12-31 and 00:30 on 2020-01-01 as the "same day", which might or might not be desired.  If daylight saving is involved, it also potentially could treat two times on a 25 hour day as being different.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the difference between the two dates (`date.difference(otherDate)`, I think) and check that the difference between those two is miniscule, which in your context might make them "equal"

But yeah, turns out date-comparisons can be a bit fiddly! :)

Comment: yeah same as @Faaatman mentioned, but it did not work. I left a comment on his.