# Can we format DateTime without Intl Package in dart / flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, package

I want to know if we can format `DateTime` without `Intl` package in a flutter project.

what I want to do is as below:

1. Compare 2 dates without time in it, in `if case`.
2. Format `datetime` String from api to given format like `yMMMMd`.
3. Only get `Time` from the given `dateTime` String.

I have done this with `intl` package but can we do it without that package dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can format DateTime without Intl package, Intl package is just ready to use methods but you can create your own format
in order to do that you need to make a List of month and maybe a List days, and as you receive the date as string from the API you have to use DateTime.parse.

I hope this example makes it clear to you

```
  List<String> monthList = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
  ];
  void yMMMMdDateFromate(String stringDateTime) {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(stringDateTime);
    String dateTimeyMMMMdDateFromate =
        '${monthList[dateTime.month - 1]} ${dateTime.day}, ${dateTime.year} ';
    print(dateTimeyMMMMdDateFromate);
  }
```

this function receive a string DateTime and print it as yMMMMd format.

and for Comparing 2 dates, after you use DateTime.parse method to convert the string to DateTime you can use

```
dateTime.isAfter(dateTime2);
dateTime.isBefore(dateTime2);
dateTime.isAtSameMomentAs(dateTime2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Compare 2 dates without time in it, in if case.

You can use [`DateTime.compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html) to compare `DateTime` objects.  If you want to ignore any time information, [you can strip off the times first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61316141/).

> 2. Format datetime String from api to given format like yMMMMd.

You can use string interpolation and `DateTime`'s fields to format them manually to a specific format.

```dart
String monthName(int month) {
  switch (month) {
    case DateTime.january:
      return 'January';
    case DateTime.february:
      return 'February';
    ...
  }
}

var dateTime = DateTime.now();
var s = '${dateTime.year} ${monthName(dateTime.month)} ${dateTime.day}';
```

Note that the above won't reorder or adjust any components based on locale.

> 3. Only get Time from the given dateTime String.

Again, you can write a helper function to extract the time components from a `DateTime` and do with them as you wish.  Flutter Material has a [`TimeOfDay`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html) class that can be constructed directly from a `DateTime` and that can represent hours and minutes, or you could easily create your own class if you want more precision.